# Repeating values after page break in proc report

Tags: sas, proc-report

I created a report of the following form:

```
ID   VAR1
      VAR2

111  1
      2
     
     3
      4

     5
      6

222  1
      2
```

I need to follow a requirement that if a page break appears inside the ID block, then the ID value must be displayed on the next page. The following form is not acceptable:

```
ID   VAR1
      VAR2

111  1
      2
     
     3
      4
-----PAGE BREAK----
     5
      6

222  1
      2
```

The page break must not occur between VAR1 and VAR2, either:

```
      VAR2

111  1
      2
     
     3
-------PAGE BREAK--------      
      4

     5
      6

222  1
      2
```

The report should look like this:

```
ID   VAR1
      VAR2

111  1
      2
     
     3
      4
-------PAGE BREAK-----
111  5
      6

222  1
      2
```

The question is - how to obtain the result? I don't want to present each ID on a separate page because unique ID blocks differ in length. So there is no simple solution like creating page break variable with different values for different IDs. I would like to avoid modifying any variables (except grouping/sorting variables) in the dataset I feed into proc report.

I would appreciate any input on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `spanrows` option, like is shown in [this paper from PharmaSUG 2011 - Beyond the Basics: Advanced REPORT Procedure Tips and Tricks
Updated for SAS® 9.2](https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2011/SAS/PharmaSUG-2011-SAS-AD02.pdf).  You don't share your code, but it goes on the `PROC REPORT` line.  Here's the example from the paper:

```
data spanrows_example;
 set sashelp.class
 sashelp.class
 sashelp.class;
run;

ods pdf file='c:\spanrows.pdf';
proc report nowd data= spanrows_example spanrows;
 col sex age name height weight;
 define sex / order;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

You can't necessarily get what you want as far as var1/var2, though, without forcing a page break if you're close to a page (which is quite challenging to calculate accurately).